# How can I shade part of a coordinate plane with tkz-euclide?

Tags: graphs, tkz-euclide

I'm graphing inequalities with tkz-euclide. I've figured out how to draw a dashed line on a coordinate grid, but I'm not sure how to shade it.

Here's what I have. How can I shade above or below the line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % coordinate plane
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.40,transform shape]
    \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
    \draw[ very thick,dashed,latex-latex] (-6,4) -- (6,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Dashed Line for Inequality]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using TikZ commands already, you can do the shading with `\fill`. Here the `opacity` needs to be set to a low value, so the grid is still visible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % coordinate plane
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.40,transform shape]
    \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
    \draw[ very thick,dashed,latex-latex] (-6,4) -- (6,0);
    \fill[green,opacity=0.1] (-6,4) -- (6,0) -- (6,-6) -- (-6,-6) -- cycle;
    \fill[red,opacity=0.1] (-6,4) -- (6,0) -- (6,6) -- (-6,6) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or, you can fill first and draw later (instead of changing `opacity`.

Comment: @balcinus you could, but this would give you white rectangles around the numbers on the axis.

Comment: I see. I guess that's because of the tkz-euclide macros used in the given code.